# Multiple CSV to one csv file with Multiple CSV sheets

Tags: c#, csv

I have few CSV file contains different data, I want to combine all this csv file into one ultimate CSV file which contains multiple sheets, under which this multiple csv are accommodated.
Till now my below code picks data from the directory and combines all CSV file into one big CSV file where it is appending the data which i do not want, instead I want multiple sheet in one file..

```
private void combineallcsv()
{
    string txtConsolidated_OS_CSV = "C:\\NWDLS\\new";
    if (txtConsolidated_OS_CSV != "")
    {
        int counter = 0;

        string[] files = (Directory.GetFiles(txtConsolidated_OS_CSV.Trim()));
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
            if (file.EndsWith(".csv"))
            {
                string[] rows = File.ReadAllLines(file);
                for (int i = 0; i < rows.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        if (counter == 0)
                        {
                            sb.Append(rows[i] + "\n");
                            counter++;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sb.Append(rows[i] + "\n");
                    }
                }
            }
            string csvfile = txtConsolidated_OS_CSV + "\\Merged_OS.csv";

            if (File.Exists(csvfile))
            {
                File.AppendAllText(csvfile, sb.ToString());
                sb.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
                File.WriteAllText(csvfile, sb.ToString());
                sb.Clear();
            }
            //using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(csvfile, true))
            //{
            //    writer.Write(sb.ToString());
            //    writer.Dispose();
            //    writer.Close();
            //}
        }
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: csv files cant be multiple sheets - they are wall of comma separated text. if you want it to be multi sheet in excel, then you need to write it to excel.

Comment: @BugFinder CSV is a extension file which opens up in excel S/W, and yes it does contains multiple sheets of values which are in Comma Separated.

Answer (score 2):

There's not such thing as "sheets" in CSV files. CSV files are just lines of text where fields are separated by some defined character. That's all.

You can use VSTO office interop or ADO.NET drivers to create "real" Excel sheets.

Comment: It is also worth noting that if you are willing to deviate from the standard CSV format, you could create your own way of handling sheets in a CSV file. You could define a special character to separate each "sheet" of csv data. You would be recreating the wheel a bit, but it is an option.

Comment: @Jared Of course you could, but true to the saying "If all you have is a hammer, all problems look like nails" people think CSV = Excel, just because when they double-click one, Excel opens. And Excel can have sheets, so CSV = Excel = Sheets. But that's not the case. And Excel just won't read a file the way you describe it. And there's no way to create a CSV file that makes Excel use several sheets.

Comment: I agree. I was just pointing out the unlikely scenario that he could create his own method if his circumstances allow it. :)

Comment: is it possible to make all sheets in excel exiting in diffrent file to one groupsheet? c#

Comment: Yes, as we said, you can write it direct to excel - but you cant do it with the csv format file because its just text